# Go Template to loop (range) out comments

Tags: mysql, templates, struct, go, range

At the end of my posts.html I need to loop over 2 elements in the Struct as without range I just get the last entry in mysql but although the rest of the structure stuff above is rendering fine the html output stops when it hits the range. Do i need to specify to only range over 2 elements in my Struct ?

```
{{range .}}
<p>{{.Name}}</p>
<p>{{.Comment}}</p>
{{end}}
```

Here is my current go code - http://play.golang.org/p/QMT12qfaoC

As an aside I have also lost the ability to render only mysql data matching the URL which also needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do i need to specify to only range over 2 elements in my Struct ?

You don't need to range over fields in a `struct`, this would be enough since you are just passing one post to `post.html` :

```
<p>{{.Name}}</p>
<p>{{.Comment}}</p>
```

Comment: If I do that I only return the last entry in mysql when I need to return all entries (comments)

Comment: For your `post.html` you are passing in a single `Post` not a slice of `Post`s, there is nothing to range over.

Comment: Ok darn it :( I need to pass in a post and comment(s) back to drawing board I think